# Há algum risco em usar o mysqli_insert_id?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Suponhamos um website com um fluxo relativamente alto. Um usuário X insere um registro no banco de dados, no mesmo tempo que outro usuário Y insere outro registro.

Considerando que o procedimento desta inserção de dados do usuário X e do usuário Y seja:

```
mysqli_query(conexao(),"insert into tabela (coluna) values ($valor)");
//INTERVALO ENTRE AS FUNÇÕES
$id_inserido = mysqli_insert_id(conexao());
```

Quais são as possibilidades de entre o intervalo do `mysqli_query` e o `mysqli_insert_id` haja uma inserção de outro usuário Y e o `mysqli_insert_id` do usuário X pegue na verdade o `id` do usuário Y?

Comment: Eu acredito que não haverá interferência... creio que ao inserir a tabela no banco já seja retornado o ID, de forma que este fica gravado internamente. Não tenho certeza. Seria legal fazer testes, colocar instruções entre essas duas linhas para ver se há essa interferência.

Comment: No caso esta inserção não seria uma tabela, mas sim uma linha dentro de uma tabela, com id auto_increment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não há risco de "misturar" ID, pelo seguinte

- Como é retornado de uma coluna `auto increment`, ele não repete.
- Como a função trabalha com a conexão atual, e cada acesso a um script PHP cria a sua conexão individual (conexões persistentes não devem ser usadas em scripts), conexões feitas por outro script não vão mudar esse valor (desde que você não misture tarefas em **paralelo na mesma página** com *threads* ou coisa do tipo, o que já não é normal fazer em PHP).
- Isto tudo partindo de que o seu `conexao()` não faça nenhuma coisa esquisita, vide considerações ao final.

Só que é importante atentar para algumas coisinhas.

- Caso você insira **múltiplas linhas**, ao contrário do que se pode imaginar, o `id` retornado é o da primeira delas. Isto foi [decidido assim](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34319) para que em ambientes de replicação seja possível deixar a sequência igual em máquinas diferentes com o uso do *insert id*.
- Devido a `mysqli_insert_id()` agir sobre a última inserção realizada, tenha certeza de chamar `mysqli_insert_id()` imediatamente após a consulta que gerou o valor para não se confundir.
- O valor da função SQL do MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()` sempre contém o valor `AUTO_INCREMENT` mais recentemente gerado, e não é reiniciado entre as consultas.

Além disso, estas duas ultimas notas merecem uma explicação em especial: Caso você tenha mais de uma consulta na mesma página, tenha o cuidado de verificar se a que precisa retornar o `id` deu erro ou não, e até se modificou algum registro de fato, para evitar por engano pegar o `id` de uma *query* anterior.

Um exemplo de cuidado extra em operações mais críticas:

```
if( mysqli_affected_rows( $con ) > 0 ) { // -1 é erro, 0 é sem inserção
   $last_id = mysqli_insert_id( $con );
} else {
   $last_id = 0;
}
```

Ou mais enxuto:

```
$last_id = mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0 ? mysqli_insert_id($con) : 0;
```

Desta forma, se deu algum erro no `insert`, ou simplesmente se não houve `insert`, não tem perigo de pegar o `id` de uma operação anterior. **Mas não precisa ficar fazendo isso sempre,** isso só faz sentido se no mesmo script tem mais de uma *query* de inserção em seguida da outra.

### Considerações adicionais:

```
mysqli_query(conexao(),"insert into tabela (coluna) values ($valor)");
```

Esse `conexao()` no seu código provavelmente deveria ser uma variável. Se você tem uma função separada pra isso, tem o risco de ter dores de cabeça diversas, se o código não for um simples *getter*.

Provavelmente seria melhor assim:

```
$con = conexao();
mysqli_query($con,"insert into tabela (coluna) values ($valor)");
$id_inserido = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

Outra coisa: se precisar de vários `id`s no mesmo script, melhor pegar logo em seguida para evitar confusão. Não pelo perigo mencionado na pergunta, mas pelo perigo de pegar os `id`s na ordem errada num código extenso:

```
$con = conexao();

mysqli_query($con,"insert into tabela (coluna) values ($valor)");
$id_inserido1 = mysqli_insert_id($con);
// intervalo
mysqli_query($con,"insert into tabela (coluna) values ($valor)");
$id_inserido2 = mysqli_insert_id($con);
// intervalo
mysqli_query($con,"insert into tabela (coluna) values ($valor)");
$id_inserido3 = mysqli_insert_id($con);
// intervalo
//
// Agora usa $id_inserido1, $id_inserido2 e $id_inserido3 como quiser
```

Manual do PHP:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.insert-id.php

Se preferir usar diretamente em MySQL;

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado pela resposta tão elaborada.

Comment: Mais um tópico para meu livro @baccoinciclopedyphp...;)

Comment: @MagicHat parte do crédito é do Vinicius, que fez a pergunta :)

Comment: Podechar vou ter um capítulo só para créditos