# Qual a boa prática para executar select após insert em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Após fazer um insert no banco de dados, retorno o id recém criado e logo faço um get deste mesmo id para executar uma outra função. Mas como é tudo muito rápido, o get vem antes de ter todo insert feito.
Estou desenvolvendo com slim framework 2 e mysql.
Como é um webservice e terão varias requisições dessas, penso que usar usleep() não seja a forma correta.
Qual a boa prática nessa situação?

Como sugestão de edição dos colegas, tradução em código:
Estou fazendo no slim framework, entao faço um post para inserir os dados

```
    $app->post('/cria', function() use ($app) {

            $id = (new \controllers())->criaEvento();
            if(isset($id)
              $app->applyHook('notifica.usuarios', $id);
        });
```

Aqui faço o insert e retorno ultimo id inserido. Após há um hook para que a aplicação notifique alguns usuarios onde terá uma lógica para qual deles

```
function criaEvento()
    {
        try {

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Tabela");
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $this->conn->lastInsertId();

            return $result;

        } catch(\PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Aqui seria o hook, mas já dá pra exemplificar, pois estou planejando a lógica

```
$app->hook('notifica.usuario', function ($id) use ($app) {
    $eventos = (new \controllers())->getEvento($id);
// aqui retorna que nao foi possivel retornar as colunas.
});
```

O insert é feito, mas pelo visto o get está mais rápido

Comment: Não está clara sua pergunta Laercio. A requisição de get precisa esperar o insert ser finalizado para obter o id do banco.

Comment: Sem código, tudo o que dissermos será especulação e provavelmente não ajudará em nada. Há questões que também precisam ser claras, como é necessário mesmo buscar do banco novamente todas as informações que você acabou de colocá-las lá? Edite a pergunta e coloque os códigos relacionados ao problema.

Comment: A "Boa prática" é não fazer isso. Se precisa do ID do registro que acaba de inserir, use o [mecanismo correto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127456/70) que o DB fornece (que tanto o MySQL quanto o PDO dispõe inclusive sem depender de SELECT). (E não existe boa prática de verdade, existe saber a razão, ou não saber a razão. Quem sabe, explica, quem não sabe chama de "boa prática" e sai fazendo sem controle e propagando confusão) - Especificamente em PHP, [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139763/70) pode interessar

Comment: Acho que agora está explicado. Não tinha colocado código pq era a lógica que estou planejando. Mas vejo que realmente não passei o que estava na minha cabeça.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma 'boa prática', seria não executar um select após para solicitar o dado que acabou de ser inserido (exceto se houver necessidade de buscar algum dado gerado pelo banco na hora da criação do registro ou outros registros).

Um possível opção, seria utilizar algum recurso de objetos para a interação com o banco de dados, vou tentar exemplificar nessa resposta:

Vamos criar duas um objeto referencia para a tabela, no exemplo teremos uma tabela users:

Este seria o objeto de user:

```
class Users extends Base{

    public $nome;

    public $email;

    public function __construct($nome, $email)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

}
```

E class `Base`, de onde o objeto será extendido:

```
class Base {

    public $id;

    public function get()
    {
        $this;
    }

    public function getTablename()
    {
        return strtolower(get_class($this));
    }

    public function getParameters()
    {
        $arr = array_keys($this->getArray());
        $response = [];
        foreach ($arr as $item){
            $response[] = '?';
        }
        return implode(', ', $response);
    }

    public function getColumns()
    {
        return (implode(',', array_keys($this->getArray())));
    }

    public function getArray()
    {
        $arr = (new ReflectionObject($this))->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

        $array_response = [];

        foreach($arr as $item){
            if(!is_null($this->{$item->name})){
                $array_response[$item->name] = $this->{$item->name};
            }
        }
        return $array_response;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return json_encode($this);
    }

}
```

Essa classe `Base`, será reponsável por converter o seu objeto User em uma query.

Depois disso, crie uma terceira classe para fazer a conexão e interações com o seu banco de dados:

```
class DBUtil {

    private $host;

    private $dbname;

    private $user;

    private $password;

    public $pdo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->host = '127.0.0.1';
        $this->dbname = 'stack';
        $this->user = 'root';
        $this->password = 'root';
        try {

            $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname, $this->user, $this->password);
        }catch (PDOException $e){
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function insert(Base $object)
    {

        $query = "INSERT INTO  {$object->getTablename()}  ( {$object->getColumns()} ) VALUES (  {$object->getParameters()} )";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

        try {
            $this->exec($stmt, $object);

        }catch (PDOException $e){
            $this->pdo->rollBack();
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        $object->id = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();

        return $object;
    }

    public function exec($stmt,Base $object)
    {
        $stmt->execute(
            array_values($object->getArray())
        );
    }
}
```

Essa terceira classe irá fazer a conexão com o banco de dados através do PDO, e repare que no método `insert` usamos a classe Base para gerar um query do objeto informado .

Como isso pode resolver o seu problema ?

Primeiro, ao invés de escrever um query de inserção, você irá criar um objeto da classe User,

```
$user = new Users($nome='Nome Da Silva',$email='teste@teste.com');
```

Inicie a classe de conexão:

```
$db = new DBUtil();
```

Com a referencia de User em $user, e de DBUtil em $db, chame:

```
$user = $db->insert($user);
var_dump($user);
```

O método insert, irá utilizar o objeto User herdado de Base para construir a query, e passar ao PDO, e irá retornar o mesmo objeto inserido, agora com o atributo `$id` com o valor da chamada de `lastInsertId` feita ao PDO.

O var_dump irá printar o objeto que você precisa, sem fazer um novo select.

Um exemplo de algo parecido com isso é o [Eloquent do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent).